# Permutations of soup can labels

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The labels from 6 different cans of soup have come off. If you were to replace them at random, in how many ways could this be done so that
a) none of the cans will be labelled correctly?
b) at least one of the cans will be labelled correctly?

The answers in the book are a) 265 and b) 455

Comment: (a) $!6$   (b) $6!-!6$

Comment: See JM's comment & see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement